# Multiple effects on single DIV element hover

Tags: html, css, image, hover

I am trying to get multiple effects on a single image hover to allow the best outcome with the least code possible. Note: I do not want jquery at all! CSS only (even 3).

So I have an image which will change on hover and at the same time cause a Div below the said image to change the background image as well (which is actually text, I just couldn't find a way to change the text so I tried the image) and with it all having the hover image on the IMG tag to have a link to the place I want.

So far I managed to get the image changed and the links working on the hover image with this:

CSS

```
.container
{
    width: 1500px;
    height: 400px;
}

.image a:hover .container
{
    background-image: url('logo-tp-text.png');
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="image">
    <a href="http://www.google.com">
        <img src="logo-tp.png" onmouseover="this.src='logo-fb.png';" onmouseout="this.src='logo-tp.png';">
    </a>
</div>

<div class="container"></div>
```

Now, as you much more experienced people than me can see, I have the image on IMG tag self onmouseovered and out to try and avoid complications on the CSS, which worked: it changes into the image I need (LOGO-FB) and reverts to LOGO-TP onmouseout, with the link working. However, it is not changing the .container background as expected on hover on the IMG tag (which is the A tag reference)

So, waiting for the beating: what am I doing wrong? Using FF 32 browser.

Comment: it is because .container is not a descendant of an anchor tag

Comment: Unfortunately, the a:hover does not work like a condition statementm it is a selector. There is no .container inside of your a tag, therefor that won't work. You may have to look into a javascript solution such as document.getElementsById("some id on container").style = "background-image : url(logo-tp-text.png)"; in your onmousover and the opposite in onmouseout

Comment: You are free to change my CSS/HTML. I had someone on a similar post do this to change the background color of a square on the right on a text link hover on the left with CSS alone, so I know it's possible... any thoughts?

Comment: The answer provided is perfect for this situation. Much cleaner than adding inline javascript, and you don't have to make the container a part of the anchor tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Css does not contains parent navigation selectors... Only descendant and following sibilings.

Since the `.container` div is a sibiling to the `.image` div, you could set the `:hover` pseudo to the div instead to the anchor:

```
.image:hover ~ .container {
     background-image: url('logo-tp-text.png');
}
```

As `~` is a general sibiling selector.

More info here: [**MDN General sibiling selector**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors)

**Also**

If the html markup stays the same as you showed, I mean, if the `.container` remains as a *immediate followed* sibiling to the `.image` div, you can also use an [**Adjacent Sibiling Selector**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)

```
.image:hover + .container {
     background-image: url('logo-tp-text.png');
}
```

Comment: SUHWEEET. Much cleaner than inline javascript. What is the support for this like cross browser?

Comment: Pretty much every browser... According to MDN, it's even IE7+ compatible.

Comment: Hi LCSALAZAR. thanks for that, it works! I know need only to figure out how to get the image logo-tp inside a div itself without crashing the code, because the logo-tp-text appears just by hovering the left side of the image (it is centered on the screen...)

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I've used the adjacent selector in my own code, I don't know why I didn't think of that here. I guess my head is too far in javascript right now. Great answer!

Comment: @AlbanLusitanae, I would recommend you to post another question to deal with that specific issue, in order not to mix up subjects. Also, if possible, remember to always, if possible, provide a http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: yep both sibling and adjacent work, still need to figure out the containment of the image, but that will be easier :D this works with multiple images and the single .container right?

Comment: @LCSALAZAR will do, appologies for that, this was my first question on the site :) again, thanks for the answer

Comment: @AlbanLusitanae, no problem at all... Welcome to SO!