# Problems with CSS DIV Multiplier Effect

Tags: html, css

I searched SO for an answer to this, but none gave me exactly what I needed. For clarification, I need a HTML CSS answer without JQUERY or JAVASCRIPT.

So following my question already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25770409/multiple-effects-on-single-div-element-hover), I proceeded and try to place the same effect of one image hover resulting in image change and different div bkground change multiplied by 6, merely to test that the .container DIV was activated, with the following (sorry LCSALAZAR, still didn't get my head around jsfiddle, coming in the future :) ):

CSS

```
body
{
background: #000000 url('river.jpg') no-repeat fixed center;
}

.container
{
width: 1500px;
height: 400px;
}

.image-tp, .image-fb, .image-pin, .image-insta, .image-yt, .image-wp
{
float: left;
margin-left: 20px;
}

.image-tp:hover + .container
{
background-image: url('logo-tp-text.png');
}

.image-fb:hover + .container
{
background-image: url('logo-tp-text.png');
}

.image-pin:hover + .container
{
background-image: url('logo-tp-text.png');
}

.image-insta:hover + .container
{
background-image: url('logo-tp-text.png');
}

.image-yt:hover + .container
{
background-image: url('logo-tp-text.png');
}

.image-wp:hover + .container
{
background-image: url('logo-tp-text.png');
}
```

HTML

```
<body>

<div class="image-tp">
<a href="#">
<img src="logo-tp.png" onmouseover="this.src='logo-tp.png';" onmouseout="this.src='logo-tp.png';">
</a>
</div>

<div class="image-fb">
<a href="#">
<img src="logo-tp.png" onmouseover="this.src='logo-fb.png';" onmouseout="this.src='logo-tp.png';">
</a>
</div>

<div class="image-pin">
<a href="#">
<img src="logo-tp.png" onmouseover="this.src='logo-pin.png';" onmouseout="this.src='logo-tp.png';">
</a>
</div>

<div class="image-insta">
<a href="#">
<img src="logo-tp.png" onmouseover="this.src='logo-insta.png';" onmouseout="this.src='logo-tp.png';">
</a>
</div>

<div class="image-yt">
<a href="#">
<img src="logo-tp.png" onmouseover="this.src='logo-yt.png';" onmouseout="this.src='logo-tp.png';">
</a>
</div>

<div class="image-wp">
<a href="#">
<img src="logo-tp.png" onmouseover="this.src='logo-fb.png';" onmouseout="this.src='logo-tp.png';">
</a>
</div>

<div class="container"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

The result was I had the LAST image DIV affecting the container DIV but none of the others. Any advise on what I am missing?

Thanks in advance

Alban

Comment: I think you mean Javascript, not Java.

Comment: is CSS actually JAVA? :| If so, yes, then I meant Javascript :)

Comment: Well, as you edited it, I guess you get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just succeeded in solving the issue :) What I did was changing the ADJACENT SIBLING for a GENERAL SIBLING selector; for future reference:

CSS

```
FIRST I HAD
.image-tp:hover + .container

NOW I HAVE
.image-tp:hover ~ .container
```

best regards
Luis Lima